# Open new custom edit form for an aspx site page only

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, custom, edit-form

Clicking the edit item icon on any aspx site page opens the `EditForm.aspx` page.

For only the `security.aspx` site page I would like the edit item icon to open my custom edit form `NewEditForm.aspx` which I have created but I can't seem to find a way to do this in SharePoint Designer 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open the list in SharePoint Designer. In the Forms section,

- click new and give a name you want for the URL (ex: neweditform).
- Select "New item Form (...),"and check "Set as default form for the selected type.
- Click OK

  and you will see the page in the Forms section.
- Then open the new page neweditform.aspx
- click the Insert Tab from the top section of the page
- From the Insert tab, insert your custom code (custom webpart for
  example)
- click Save.
- Refresh your site and you should see your custom form when you click
  edit.